# Source File Validation in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to validate a source input File based on below Data Quality indicators

```
1. The record Count of the Source File must be greater than 0
2.columns "id" and "AsofDate", should not contain any null values.
3. The “AsOfDate” column Value must be equal to the Reporting Date (Input Parameter to Job).
4. Based on the above Indicators, log these information in either some text file or database table.
```

Am Attaching the sample Source input File

[image]

Comment: You have asked 8 other questions and not selected any answers.  Please review some of the answers to your questions and mark any correct.  As others have commented on your previous questions, the Stack Overflow community is more than willing to help you, however, you are expected to reward the community's effort by marking answers correct (the check mark next to the answer), up-voting helpful posts (the up arrow next to the question), refining your questions, etc.

Comment: @David: i have marked correct for the answers they have given.

Comment: Going from 0% to 50% is an excellent start.  For clarification to the 4th item in your question, are you wanting to write the individual rows that pass the validation rules 1-3?  Are you just wanting to write a log record of the file name along with an indicator as to which rule passed?  What have you done to try an accomplish your request?

Comment: i would like to write individual rows that pass the validation rules 1-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a `Data Flow Task` and add a variable to your solution: RowCount

In your data flow task, you could use the following items:

1. Flat File Source
2. Row Counter
3. Derived Column
4. Conditional Split
5. Destination

`Flat File Source`

Create your typical flat file data source

`Row Counter`

Add a counter and set the variable of the counter equal to your row count variable.

`Derived Column`

I'd rather do expression logic in a derived column

- New Column 1: If RowCount > 0 return true else false
- New Column 2: If ID is null or AsOfDate is null return false else true
- New Column 3: If AsOfDate = InputDate return true else return false

`Conditional Split`

Since your new columns are booleans, you should be able to do something like as follows:

Output 1:
`Column1 && Column2 && Column3`

`Destination`

Connect Output 1 from the conditional split to the destination of your choice.

Comment: HI David, I tried by connecting Output 1 with outputdestination and default Output of conditional split to another ff destination, but am not able to get the result of output1. when i open outputdestination file it is empty.

Comment: You can start debugging a data flow by placing data viewers at the step before the conditional split.  Check to see the value of each of the three derived columns.  When you determine which derived column contains the  false value, check the conditions of the column to see why the column is false.  An example of a possible problem with validation rule 3 could be that the date values are not in the same format: IE you are not comparing `2012-03-19` to `03/19/2012 08:20:00.000`